# Infinite Loop and Rotation of Array

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, loops, for-loop

so I have this list,

**List:** [0, 0, 1, 0, 1];

And I need made a algorithm with a `for` to show all the list (`list[i]`).

When I am in first array position, I can do `list[i-2] and list[i-1]`, with this I can see the elements of the last position and the position before the last position.

**Exemple :** `list[0] = 0; list[i-1] = list[4] = 1; list[i-2] = list[3] = 0;` so I can go to the last position and start from there.

But when I do, `list[i+1]` in the last position I got a **IndexError: list index out of range** from the terminal.

**My question is:** If I was in the last positions and I want again come to  from the first one and keep doing the for loop, to see infinite times all array elements from all positions, How I can do it?
If the size of my array it is 5, and I am in second position(`list[1]`) in the loop and want do `list[i + 11]`, how can I put this representing this, `list[2]`?

I am trying make this on python.

Comment: You want something like `list[i%len(i)]`?

Comment: Ha, missed the lookup part. They should be using the wrapping with modulo then. But they can throw in `islice` with `cycle` if they want

Comment: @MosesKoledoye this dont come to the begining of array again :s
it is just a internal array funcionalaties.

Comment: @JuanT I will try.

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to ask, and it looks like no one else has a clear idea either.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Imagine a loop to show all element of the array, the size of array is 7 and I want make a loop 10 times, so when it is on last position (on list[6]) they need to come to the begining again and show 3 elements from there.

Comment: That would be a cycle. See the linked question and its answers.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 yes but if I have a array like [1,2,3,4,5,6], and want start from one time in second, and next start from last position, I can do it with this itertools.cycle

Comment: I am glad to hear that you can do it with the methods in the provided link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement such an "infinite iterator" as follows:

```
def infinite_iterator(lst):    
    i = 0
    def next():        
        global i
        while True:
            result = lst[i % len(lst)]
            i += 1
            yield result
    return next()
```

and use it with:

```
lst = [1,2,3,4,5]    
iter = infinite_iterator(lst)

for i in range(17): # 17 is just an example, you can put any number or `while True:` 
    print(next(iter))
```

Comment: Thank you man! Its exactly what I am trying find. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using the modulo operator, which returns the remainder of the division of its two operands. In this case, you would do the following: `list[i%num_of_elements]`, where num_of_elements is a variable holding the number of elements in the list.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your asking about rotating arrays, if this isn't what you meant, just comment.

```
def rotateLeft(li):
    return li[1:] + [li[0]]

def rotateRight(li):
    return [li[len(li)-1]] + li[:len(li)-1]

li = [1,2,3,4,5]

print (rotateLeft(li))
print (rotateRight(li))
```

Comment: `rotateRight(li)` can be simplified like `return [li[-1]] + li[:-1]`

Comment: Or, perhaps more efficient version of `rotateLeft()` would be `li.append(li.pop(0))` (though I don't know how it works internally in python).